# Join two data sets in SSRS 2012

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have two datasets from a same data source in my SSRS report. I want to join both of them, the employee id is the common column in both. Is there a way to join both datasets in expression?

Comment: Why not join them in the underlying SQL?

Comment: I don't know about Shashi's case, but I just had this issue land in my lap and changing the underlying SQL is not an option because one of the data sources is a stored procedure that is widely used - changing it would touch a lot of existing processes.

Answer (score 4):

According to the MSDN page on [Lookup Function (Report Builder and SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx), you can use a secondary dataset in SSRS like this:

> In the following example, assume that a table is bound to a dataset that includes  a field for the product identifier ProductID. A separate dataset called "Product" contains the corresponding product identifier ID and the product name Name.
>
> In the following expression, **Lookup** compares the value of ProductID to ID in each row of the dataset called "Product"  and, when a match is found, returns the value of the Name field for that row.
>
> ```
> =Lookup(Fields!ProductID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!Name.Value, "Product")
> ```

Comment: Thank you all experts, i was able to solve it by joining in underlying sql and thanks for the lookup function example as well.